"A modifier in clause structure" — Is it possible to understand by this phrase what head the modifier modifies?
Sometimes I come across the phrase "a modifier in clause structure".
Can we draw the unambiguous conclusion from this phrase about what head such a modifier modifies?
If we can, then what head is implied?
For example, the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 1265:

Modifiers in clause structure:
(1) They are saving up to buy a washing-machine.
(2) They arrived home to find the house had been burgled.
(3) He was a fool to say he’d go.
(4) Liz was lying by the pool reading a novel.

The phrases in bold are modifiers in clause structure.
What heads do they modify?

Didn't you ask a similar question earlier today? It looks like it's been deleted. If there was a problem you should have edited the question, not deleted and reposted.

Aren't they adverbial, modifying the main verb in each case? Saving why. Arrived how. Was in what way. Lying why.

@Barmar The deleted question was about the heads of modifiers. This one is about the heads modifiers modify. That is, they are absolutely different from each other. As far as I understand, users can edit their question only to change the explanation of why the question was asked (i.e. to make it clearer) but not to change the main question itself. Tell me please why you disagree?

The non-finite clauses on your examples don't modify a head, but a verb phrase. In (1) for example, "to buy a washing-machine" modifies the VP "saving up".

Further, the term 'modifier in clause structure' is intended to distinguish those modifiers from the ones in phrase structure, i.e. in noun/adjective/adverb/preposition/determinative phrases.

@BillJ You wrote: In (1) for example, "to buy a washing-machine" modifies the VP "saving up". Am I right that, by analogy: "to find the house had been burgled" in (2) modifies the VP "arrived home"; "to say he’d go" in (3) modifies the VP "was a fool"; "reading a novel" in (4) modifies the VP "lying by the pool" ? Thanks.

@Loviii Yes, I would say so.

@BillJ And what is the rationale for limiting the modification to the verb phrase of the main clause rather than the main clause in its entirety?

Check out the tree diagram on p473: the head is the VP. In other words, modifiers in clause structure generally modify a unit made up of the predicator (verb at the head of the clause) and its complements.

However, often it's necessary to include more than just the predicator and its complements in the VP acting as head. For example, in the following sentence, it would be best to say that the modifier because he was late modifies the head ate his lunch quickly, not just ate his lunch.

He ate his lunch quickly because he was late.


I don't think it's a suitable tree here for diagramming a modifier in clause structure. I think CGEL used that tree structure simply to make a comparison with the adjacent nominalised version [52a]: as they say "to bring out the parallelism ...". Ordinarily, they would label "carefully analysed the issues" as 'Predicate: VP', with 'analysed' as 'Predicator: V' with its 'Object: NP' ("the issues").

@BillJ You wrote: Ordinarily, they would label "carefully analysed the issues" as 'Predicate: VP'. Do you mean that in this case "carefully" modifies "analysed"? Thanks.

@Loviii No: I'd say that "carefully"modifies the VP "analysed the issues".

@Loviii Note also that "carefully analysed" is not here a constituent.

You gave the sentence "He ate his lunch quickly because he was late" as an example of modifiers in clause structure. In this regard, am I right that: “because he was late” is a modifier in clause structure (where the clause is "He ate his lunch quickly because he was late"); “quickly” is also a modifier in clause structure (where the clause is "He ate his lunch quickly", i.e. without "because he was late") ? Thanks.

I wouldn't say it was correct to analyze it as having two separate clauses. It's all part of one main clause, which I'd say would be best analyzed as having a layered analysis for the VP (or Predicate:VP), as shown in the diagram above. Imagine another layer in the diagram that was once again split into a Head:VP ate his lunch quickly and Modifier:PP because he was late.

@Loviii No: To talk of 'separate clauses' would misleading. "He ate his lunch quickly" is not here a clause, but just part of one. Because he was late" is not a clause; it's a PP (preposition phrase) with the prep "because" as head with the clause "he was late" as its complement. The PP is functioning as an adjunct -- a modifier in clause structure, part of the VP.

@Loviii I've added an answer containing a simplified tree diagram of DW256's example: "He ate his lunch quickly because he was late".


He ate his lunch quickly because he was late.

Here is how I would diagram DW256's example. As you can see, "quickly" and "because he was late" are both modifiers in clause structure, part of the predicate VP.


There is one thing I totally can't understand. According to your diagram, two modifiers in clause structure "quickly" and "because he was late" modify "ate" (i.e. not "ate his lunch"). But in the sentence "Mary carefully analysed the issues", you said the modifier in clause structure "carefully" modifies not "analysed" but "analysed the issues". Could you explain to me please when a modifier modifies only one verb and when a modifier modifies the verb together with the complement? Thanks.
